# VueJs dynamically bind data to a route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have an object which has all the question paper ids and I render those ids to a table as well.
What is need is when some one hit the `Take Exam` button,
relevant `paperid` should pass to the route.
I tried

```
this.$router.push('/startExam/{{paperid}}');
```

and

```
this.$router.push('/startExam/this.paperid');
```

but both doesn't worked.
How do I dynamically pass data to a route?
My code is here.

```
<tbody>
      <tr v-for="paperid in QuestionPapersArray">
        <td>{{paperid}}</td>
        <td></td>
        <th></th>
        <th><button class="btn" @click="takeExam">Take Exam</button></th>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

and

```
methods:{
    takeExam(){
      console.log("Inside the function");
      this.$router.push('/startExam');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tbody>
      <tr v-for="paperId in QuestionPapersArray">
        <td>{{ paperId }}</td>
        <td></td>
        <th></th>
        <th><button class="btn" @click="takeExam(paperId)">Take Exam</button></th>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

---

Try the following.

```
methods: {
  takeExam (paperId) {
    this.$router.push(`/startExam/${paperId}`)
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can try the following inside the `takeExam()` method

```
this.$router.push({
  path: '/startExam',
  params: {
    id: paperId
  }
})
```

Your route config file should be `path: '/startExam/:id'`

Comment: ReferenceError: paperid is not defined. May be there is so many paper ids in the table. Are there any way to pass relevant paper id to the method?

Comment: I've modified my answer.

Comment: Accept the answer and close this question?